# Angular 4 Routing & Navigation

Tags: angular-routing, angular4

Мне надо сделать сайт, на котором могут регистрироваться 2 типа юзеров:  например, доктор и пациент.
Для каждого из них для главной и других страниц разные контенты, например у доктора: список пациентов, список обращений, связь с аптеками, и т.д., а у пациента: мои доктора, мои болезни, мои обращения и т.д.
Но не хочется делать кашу в одном компоненте и через `*ngIf`показывать контенты, и  URL тоже менять не желательно.
Как сделать так, чтоб по одному и тому же адресу, в зависимости от типа юзеров, подключить разные компоненты?

Comment: думаю надо сделать так, на уровне апи.
Сначала, у вас должен быть юзеры с ролями. В данной случай это доктор и пациент. Потом для каждого юзера свой токен.
То есть в базе, в таблице юзерс: Id, name, IdToken, roleId.
Потом будете проверять при авторизации, если роль и токен есть в базе, то отправляете нужный контент в виде json. То есть название компонентов тоже сохраните в базе.

Comment: Это не вариант! во первых апишка разрабатывается отдельно от фронтенда, и работают другие программисты, а во вторых вопрос был как это сделать в angular

Answer (score 0):

Не очень согласен с создателем вопроса по поводу, что не менять пути в адресной строке, ибо тогда пользователь, сохранив в закладки, не может попасть на ту страницу, куда ему надо в последствии.

Но все можно сделать. Просто разделить роутингом, например (https://next.angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5):

Основной путь **поликлиника.ру/**

После входа пользователя с правами "*доктор*" он попадает в путь **поликлиника.ру/personal/**

**поликлиника.ру/personal/listPatient**

**поликлиника.ру/personal/listContactsApteka** и т.д.

А пользователь "*пациент*" в путь **поликлиника.ру/patient/**

**поликлиника.ру/patient/listDoctor**

**поликлиника.ру/patient/calendar** и т.д.

А дальше уже как душе угодно. И на каждый роут вешать одни и те же компоненты, раз они у вас одинаковые. Зато каждый будет видеть только свое, спокойно сохранять в закладки страницы и пользоваться системой.